# Serialize not processing on firefox

Tags: jquery

I'm having strange situation with this little code

```
     $('#plac').click(function(){
    //Send data to the other script
    $.post( 'http://inwestycyjneprzebudzenie.pl/wp-content/plugins/newsletter/do/subscribe.php', $('form').serialize(), function(data, textStatus) {


    });
});
```

On google chrome it works, but on firefox, or any other browsers it doesn't. 
I've noticed if I modify the code like that

```
       $('#plac').click(function(){
    //Send data to the other script
    $.post( 'http://inwestycyjneprzebudzenie.pl/wp-content/plugins/newsletter/do/subscribe.php', $('form').serialize(), function(data, textStatus) {


    });
 alert ('Thanks');
});
```

It does work, but I don't like having alert after the click, how can I resolve this one ? ;)

Comment: please explain what it doenst work. You code send an ajax post request on a click event and does nothing else with its responce. So, what doens't work exaclty?

Comment: I got the form with two different submitions. So after this click it should go to the paypal, and save the email into newsletter database. And as I said it works on chrome, but doesn't on any others. But if I add this alert it works on both. So it looks like on other browsers it's not being processed just after the click, only after the alert shows ...

Comment: sounds like one browser waits for ajax to execute, while the others go on with the script without response from your ajax call. Perhaps you can modify your code to be executed on Ajax's success response?

Comment: I've been thinking about it ;) however tried to find something else , but is there anything else ;) ?

Comment: with the code you provide, i can't think of anything else. Of cource, if your ajax only saves an email to database, then there is nothing wrong with this setup. BUT if you need to validate its an email and that you dont have it in db already, then you must wait for ajax response.

Comment: Ye I do validate. Ok, thanks man, I'll try it ;)